# Is it natural to say "You're showing too much flesh on your chest. Change into new clothes!"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

The woman in the picture showed too much flesh on her chest. It is either too sexy or not good for her lung in winter, for example.

Say, you have a teen daughter who wears things like that.

Is it natural to say to your daughter "**You're showing too much flesh on your chest. Change into new clothes!**"?

Comment: No, awful. Too much skin. Not new clothes, **Other clothes**. Natural, nicht. Idiomatic.

Comment: It's neither natural nor polite. It would be very insulting to speak to a woman like that. 
If you must comment, I would suggest "Don't you think that neckline is rather low?" "That dress is rather low-cut, isn't it?"

Comment: @KateBunting, but say you have a teen daughter, you must say something to her if she wears it. I saw school girls being screened for what they wear in movies, and thus they must say something to it.

Comment: “too much skin” is more polite and can refer to any skin. This particular bit of skin would be “too much cleavage”, but you would only use that with friends or family.

Comment: @Tom - you _really think_ that's "too much flesh"? Is it 1820 where you are?

Comment: Well, OK, if it's a teenage daughter "I'm not letting you go out in such a low-cut dress. You must go and get changed."

Comment: "Showing too much flesh on your chest" is a very bad way of phrasing it - it sounds like the alternative is literal removal of the woman's flesh, revealing bloody muscle and bone.